# Security of devices who implement Face Unlock on Android 10

Tags: android, security, android-10.0, android-biometric

I would like to understand how secure facial recognition on android 10 is.

First of all, I haven't found much information about the new google system and how secure it is, and I also haven't found any information about what android devices can contain ( which means they have the physical requirements ) the new android 10 facial recognition.

I would love if you can explain why/if it is more secure now then before.

Comment: I've edited this question slightly to avoid it being closed for needing more focus, and answered it in that reduced scope.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is not a universal Android face unlock - each device maker creates their own implementation.  However, they all do need to meet certain [security requirements](https://source.android.com/security/biometric/measure) referenced in the Android Compatibility Definition Document for Android 10.

Strong biometrics (such as Pixel's face-unlock feature) must have a spoof acceptance rate ("The chance that a biometric model accepts a previously recorded, known good sample") of *at most* 7%, and a false accept rate ("how often a model mistakenly accepts a randomly chosen incorrect input") of *at most* 1 in 50000.

Of course, this is the minimum security level: implementations may be stronger than the minimum required.

There are other strength classes of biometrics (weak, convenience) - you can check that link for detailed descriptions and requirements for each strength class.